# QGIS 3.4 - Rasterize creates layers with 1.79769e+ 308 min/max values

Tags: qgis, raster, rasterization, raster-conversion

I have tried searching on here for my issues, read many threads, but to no avail.

Essentially, I am trying to convert a line feature to a raster so that I can run proximity on it - because I want to use it in the raster calculator to find areas that are both X elevation and X distance from a road. I have buffered the line (road) by 200m, and want to convert the buffered layer to a raster.

Whichever way I run the converter, I get the same non-existent layer with min/max  1.79769e+ 308 values.

Any suggestions?

v3.4.4

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Rasterize (vector to raster)' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'BURN' : 1, 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'EXTENT' : '-16.95314021128497,-16.0864476950926,27.984934352626247,28.611619710488423 [EPSG:4326]', 'FIELD' : None, 'HEIGHT' : 1000, 'INIT' : None, 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/Ben/Documents/University/EnvGIS/qgis/buffer_road.gpkg|layername=buffer_road', 'INVERT' : False, 'NODATA' : 0, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/Ben/Documents/University/EnvGIS/qgis/raster_road_w_buffer.tif', 'UNITS' : 0, 'WIDTH' : 1000 }

GDAL command:
gdal_rasterize -l buffer_road -burn 1.0 -ts 1000.0 1000.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -te -16.95314021128497 27.984934352626247 -16.0864476950926 28.611619710488423 -ot Float32 -of GTiff C:/Users/Ben/Documents/University/EnvGIS/qgis/buffer_road.gpkg C:/Users/Ben/Documents/University/EnvGIS/qgis/raster_road_w_buffer.tif
GDAL command output:
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

Execution completed in 0.30 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':C:/Users/Ben/Documents/University/EnvGIS/qgis/raster_road_w_buffer.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Rasterize (vector to raster)' finished
```

Raster information log

```
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Raster information' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/Ben/Documents/University/EnvGIS/qgis/raster_road_w_buffer.tif', 'MIN_MAX' : False, 'NOGCP' : False, 'NO_METADATA' : False, 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/Users/Ben/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_068aa7c8382d44f4974580e307eb6f9f/630ed4178e7946888b29335bca0f80b6/OUTPUT.html', 'STATS' : True }

GDAL command:
gdalinfo -stats C:/Users/Ben/Documents/University/EnvGIS/qgis/raster_road_w_buffer.tif
GDAL command output:
ERROR 1: C:/Users/Ben/Documents/University/EnvGIS/qgis/raster_road_w_buffer.tif, band 1: Failed to compute statistics, no valid pixels found in sampling.

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF

Files: C:/Users/Ben/Documents/University/EnvGIS/qgis/raster_road_w_buffer.tif

Size is 1000, 1000

Coordinate System is:

PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 28N",

GEOGCS["WGS 84",

DATUM["WGS_1984",

SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],

AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],

PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],

UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],

AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],

PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],

PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],

PARAMETER["central_meridian",-15],

PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],

PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],

PARAMETER["false_northing",0],

UNIT["metre",1,

AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],

AXIS["Easting",EAST],

AXIS["Northing",NORTH],

AUTHORITY["EPSG","32628"]]

Origin = (-16.953140211284971,28.611619710488423)

Pixel Size = (0.000866692516192,-0.000626685357862)

Metadata:

AREA_OR_POINT=Area

Image Structure Metadata:

INTERLEAVE=BAND

Corner Coordinates:

Upper Left ( -16.9531402, 28.6116197) ( 19d29'20.02"W, 0d 0' 0.93"N)

Lower Left ( -16.9531402, 27.9849344) ( 19d29'20.02"W, 0d 0' 0.91"N)

Upper Right ( -16.0864477, 28.6116197) ( 19d29'20.00"W, 0d 0' 0.93"N)

Lower Right ( -16.0864477, 27.9849344) ( 19d29'20.00"W, 0d 0' 0.91"N)

Center ( -16.5197940, 28.2982770) ( 19d29'20.01"W, 0d 0' 0.92"N)

Band 1 Block=1000x2 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray

NoData Value=0

Metadata:

STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=0

Execution completed in 0.16 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/Ben/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_068aa7c8382d44f4974580e307eb6f9f/630ed4178e7946888b29335bca0f80b6/OUTPUT.html'}

Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Raster information' finished
HTML output has been generated by this algorithm.
Open the results dialog to check it.
```

Comment: The output raster extent must include the extension of the input vector layer. If you burn a fixed value, do not assign that value for nodata. Do some of these tips solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gabriel. I have been setting the output extent to a layer that definitely contains the input vector (in my case, the island outline is set as the extent for the roads on the island). I have been trying to set the fixed value to 1 and the nodata value to 0, but no luck.

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/310885/edit) your question to include the output log of the _Rasterize_ tool as preformatted text in the body of your question.

Comment: Also specify which version of QGIS 3.4 you use.

Comment: Have done so! v 3.4.4

Comment: What is the data type of the field _convert_ in the _buffer_road_ layer? You can try: + Use the same _buffer_road_ layer for the output extents parameter; + Use a fixed value to burn instead of _convert_ values; + Save the output to a folder that not include blank spaces (this is a best practice, I don't know if it can be a problem here but try it). Also I can see, in your first attemp, that GDAL fails to access the temp folder, that can be a problem.

Comment: Also, if you can include the output log of the _Raster Information_ tool with the raster_convert.tif as input, and the _Read and display image statistics_ option ticked, we can see if there is a problem with the extents and/or resolution of the generated raster dataset.

Comment: Hi Gabriel - the data type is just an integer, I put 1s in just to try it as an alternative to setting the burn value to 1. I have tried using the fixed burn values instead, same result. I will do the output log for raster information as you suggested now. User2856 - I have used fields to burn values and set values, same results.

Comment: Ran completely from scratch this morning, removing any spaces in file path, ensuring burn values set to 1 and 0, nothing burning from a field. See original post for log. I have also now put the log for raster information,

Comment: your bounding box is (probably) wrong seems to be in degrees while process is working in UTM 28N

Comment: Ahhh yes - thank you Ian I think that is it. I had reprojected the roads in UTM 28N in order to buffer them in metres vs degrees. I have reprojected buffered layer back to WGS84 and is now working - thank you!

Comment: Got the same problem. How to solve this......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the definition of the extents of the output raster.

When using an input layer with a Coordinate Reference System, but defining the extension of the output raster through a layer with a different CRS, the *Rasterize* tool creates a raster with the CRS of the input layer, but with the coordinates of its extents referred to the other system.

As a result, nothing that was in the input layer is found in those coordinates and the output raster contains only nodata values.

**The solution is to use both layers defined under the same CRS (reprojecting some of them), when it is intended to *Raterize* a layer with the extents defined by another layer.**

Comment: I still get this problem when I use the extents of the layer I'm rasterising, or if I drag extents manually on the canvas. If I use georeferenced units I get attempt to create 0x0 dataset is illegal error, if I use pixels it gets created but with no valid cells.

Comment: @dez93_2000 Are you assigning values greater than zero to vertical and horizontal resolution?

Comment: yes - should I NOT be? Playing around with it, it seems res values are inversely proportional to number of rows/columns created, which makes sense.

Comment: @dez93_2000 They are the resolution. In pixels, is directly proportional (in fact, equivalent) to the number of rows and columns. In units, inversely proportional (divide the extent over the units resolution to obtain the number of rows or columns).

Comment: Yep, that's what I figured. I've played around with different values which create correspondingly different sized outputs in terms of row/column numbers (if using pixels), but they're statistically not valid. Not to worry, I remembered I gave up on this in QGis before and did it in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It could be to do with the size of the space you're using to save the layers in. Not sure about this, but the same thing was happening to me and it turned out my drive was full. I deleted some things and it worked, but I also made sure my CRS info was the same for each layer etc and went through that very carefully.